# Should .css.scss be added to precompile for production? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In the following code for production.rb:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w[active_admin.css active_admin.js]
```

**Do I need to manually put in `application.css.scss.erb`? Since the comment only states `application.css` that is auto precompiled by rails 3.1**

Answer (score 1):

No -- application.css will be generated from application.css.scss -- you only need to add additional files that you're adding that would not normally be compiled into application.css